# DNS Fails on VPN into Azure Network with DNS server on Peered network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have the following setup in Azure:

ResourceGroup 1

- Virtual Machine which is DNS & DC Server 'My1stVM'
- Virtual Network 'vNet1'
- Peering from vNet1 to vNet2

Resource Group 2

- Virtual Network 'vNet2'
- Peering from vNet2 to vNet1
- Virtual Machine 'My2ndVM'
- Virtual Network Gateway

When I create a VPN connection from my home laptop into the Virtual Network Gateway, I can:

- Connect to VPN successfully
- RDP onto My2ndVM by internal ip address only, cannot do it by FQDN or computername
- Ping My2ndVM by intenral ip address only, cannot do it by FQDN or computername

I don't understand why I cannot ping my computername or FQDN.

If I do NSLookUp I get

```
C:\Users\MyUser>nslookup
DNS request timed out.
timeout was 2 seconds.
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.167.64.4
```

192.167.64.4 is the correct internal IP for the DNS Server

If I try to Ping 192.167.64.4 I get:

```
C:\Users\MyUser>ping 192.167.64.4

Pinging 192.167.64.4 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 193.204.206.100: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 193.204.206.100: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 193.204.206.100: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 193.204.206.100: TTL expired in transit.

Ping statistics for 192.167.64.4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

Is anyone able to help me understand the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you use Point-to-site VPN  connect to vnet 2?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I'm gonna try doing a tracert then in a bit then il post my results

Comment: Are you try to use your home laptop to ping the DNS server?

Comment: Yes this is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, your home laptop connect to Vnet2 via P2S VPN, you want to use laptop to ping `My1stVM`, am I correctly?

You are **not** able to communicate across the VPN, because **there is no derived transitive relationship** across VPN.

You can ping Vnet2 via `P2S VPN`, and vm2 can ping vm1 via `vnet peering`, but you can't ping vm1.

> I don't understand why I cannot ping my computername or FQDN.

Because you can't access to DNS server. DNS does not work for you.

Comment: You said 'Because you can't access to DNS server. DNS does not work for you.' Why is this? I can only ping My2ndVM by ip and not hostname, which is what we want to resolve, is there any way of making this work?

Comment: VPN does not support  communicate across VPN. p2s use SSTP tunnel IP address to communicate, can't use FQDN to access vm2. If you want to use FQDN to access it, you move your DNS service to VM2, and deploy site-to-site VPN between home laptop and Vnet2.

Comment: Do you mean VPN does not support communication across peering? Alternative to moving DNS services to VM2, I guess the other option is to move Gateway to vNET1?

Comment: Yes, VPN does not support communication across peering.  You are right, the other option is to move Gateway to Vnet1, then you can't ping Vnet2.

Comment: Ok I am going to try setting up DNS on My2ndVM, should I be able to have My1stVM as primary DNS and My2ndVM as secondary DNS?

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes, you can do it, but if you want to use dns, you should use s2s VPN to connect laptop and vnet1 or vnet2, also, only one tunnel can be use.

Comment: Its a single machine connecting in, I dont want to connect the whole site in at the moment

Comment: @Jeffrey  site to site vpn

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [gateway transit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview#gateways-and-on-premises-connectivity) to support your scenario.

1. On "Peering from vNet1 to vNet2" enable the option "Use remote gateways"
2. On "Peering from vNet2 to vNet1" enable the option "Allow gateway transit"

Source : [Configure VPN gateway transit for virtual network peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-peering-gateway-transit)

Comment: This worked for me: I had exactly the same symptoms trying to join a local machine to an Azure AD DS domain. After having set the correct Peering settings, I was able to achieve what I wanted and I now have no DNS issues anymore. Thanks a lot!